# How can I provide a formatted date to a text input field?

Tags: javascript, date, format

I want to add the current date in the format DD.MM.YY, i.e. 31.05.2017 to an input field with id "dateFrom".

```
$( function() {
    document.getElementById('dateFrom').value = Date();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

convert it

```
...value=new Date().toLocaleDateString()
```

Comment: yes i know, in our country we use this  as a placeholder for previous code or text. Sorry.

Comment: were living in the same... just wanted to point out that it might be better to put in a nother line or to simply leave it away in a codinf context as it can be missunderstood

Comment: Ok, next time ... :-)

Comment: Output is ``Wed May 31 2017 10:27:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)``, not ``31.05.2017``, for example.

Comment: my output is '31.5.2017' , perhaps we have different locale settings? I don´t know your locale settings... look at the javascript date Object and build your dateString....

Answer (score -1):

```
Date()
```

returns an Object. Assigning an Object is not what you want. You may want a String:

```
Date().toString()
```

or in the shortform:

```
Date()+""
```

Note that Date works, but its more common to use the new operator on it:

```
""+new Date()
```

This returns a Time String. If you want sth special, you must construct it:

```
(d=>[d.getDate(),d.getMonth()+1,d.getYear()].join("."))(new Date());
```